# What are some good resources for learning the Rails codebase internals?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been developing in Rails for about 3 years now, and would like to learn more about the Rails internals themselves.  Rails 3 supposedly provides nice API's for integrating more closely with Rails, but I'm having a hard time finding documentation on how to use them.  Here are some examples of what i'm looking for:

Rails Initialization Process
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html

Arel Walkthrough
http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough

Routing Walkthrough
http://railscasts.com/episodes/231-routing-walkthrough
http://railscasts.com/episodes/232-routing-walkthrough-part-2

Crafting Rails Applications
http://pragprog.com/book/jvrails/crafting-rails-applications

Are there any other good resources that an help as a guided tour of how Rails works?
(and please don't say read the source code..    I'm looking for a more guided explanation)

Comment: You say you're not looking for a "read the source code" answer, but it really is a great approach - you can tell because the Railscasts you link to do exactly that! You'll be surprised how quickly you pick it up

Comment: I'm only asking the question, because I do read through the source code, and find its not enough.  Maybe i'm just slow..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Ruby Metaprogramming Book](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) has some chapters in the end teaching how ActiveRecord internals is made up.

Answer (score 4):

You may like this articles:

http://piotrsarnacki.com/2010/07/31/rails3-modularity/

http://piotrsarnacki.com/2010/06/18/rails-internals-railties/

But, you should start writing such articles by own, ie try to write how controllers instance variables are visible in views or prepare description of all rails modules and classes - this will make you much more familliar with rails.